# python - power spectrum of real data

Tags: python, analysis

I'm trying to show trends in my data and therefore I have performed a fast fourier transform on the data. But as you can see on the plot below it wasn't very effective. The code that produced that plot is:

```
N = 344
T = 16
x = np.array(data_plot_multi_year["x"])
y = np.array(data_plot_multi_year["y"])
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = numpy.linspace(0, 6000, N) 
plt.plot(xf[1:], np.abs(yf[1:]))
plt.show()
```

where data_plot_multi_year is defined as follows:

```
data_plot_multi_year1 = {"x": [], "y": [], "label": []}
        for label, coord in L_B_1_mean.items():
            data_plot_multi_year1["label"].append(label)
            data_plot_multi_year1["x"].append(int(label[:4]) - lowest_year_multi) * 365 + int(label[-3:]))
            data_plot_multi_year1["y"].append(coord)
```

and L_B_1_mean is a dictionary looking like:

```
2008130 8.41601085161
2010261 7.24693188673
2005327 8.42464344534
2010149 8.00870105201
2007024 8.21963603414
2007184 7.99993132472
2003226 7.39439113433
2004005 8.3723784148
2017266 7.93883178307
.....
```

[image: FFT]

Somebody told me to do a power spectrum of the same data. I've read several other threats on here where they are using `rfft` and `rfftfreq` but as i have never done something like that before I dont know where to start.

Even though this is ploting something very weird, would something like this be a start?:

```
T = 16
x = np.array(data_plot_multi_year["x"])
y = np.array(data_plot_multi_year["y"])
ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))**2   
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(y.size, T)
idx = np.argsort(freqs)
plt.plot(freqs[idx], ps[idx])
```

Comment: You do not have a trend in your data, but a lot of variability. Perhaps both seasonal and interannual. Therefore, I would suggest other methods for analysis like FFT and Wavelets. The first is very simple, might not give much, but perhaps you get some meaningful stuff with the advance FFT (Wavelets).